# How to display multiple files for download using css php and html?

Tags: php, html, css

I am still learning PHP and I have written a code to show files that are supposed to be downloaded when a user clicks the file name. I  need the files to be displayed in a  table that has columns with titles such as **file title**, **uploaded date**, and **size**. How can I display in such a way?

**this is my code**

```html
<table id="t02" width="90%" border="1px" cellpadding="5" align="center">
    <th>
      Title
    </th>
    <th>
      Uploaded Date
    </th>
    <th>
      File Size
    </th>
       <?php
          if ($handle = opendir('uploads/it/hnd/')) {

            while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

              if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

                // echo '<a href="/prac/admin/">'.$entry.'</a>'."<br>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo '<a href="uploads/it/hnd/'.$entry.'"' .'download="'.$entry.'">'.$entry.'</a>'.'</td>';       
          
                }
            }

            closedir($handle);
        }



        ?>
    
  </table>
```

Comment: I would recommend that you start by going through some tutorials about tables: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: I know about tables, but my question is what php code can i put to display the file date and time of the uploaded file and the size of the file under those 2 empty columns, file size and uploaded date

Comment: Well, your table markup is invalid. For example, you're missing the `<tr></tr>` around the headers. You're also adding a opening `<tr>` on each iteration, just adding one column, but you're not closing the `</tr>`'s at any point.

Comment: I don't know how are your files stored, can you show us the datas you get?

Comment: Have you tought of using mysql to simply store the file path and add informations about it so you can display everything in a single query/phpfile?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.stat.php http://php.net/manual/fr/function.filemtime.php otherwise php.net have lots of usefull functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table id="t02" width="90%" border="1px" cellpadding="5" align="center">
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Uploaded Date</th>
    <th>File Size</th>
</tr>

<?php
    $files = glob('uploads/it/hnd/*');
    foreach($files as $file){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><a href="'.$file.'" download="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></td>';
        echo '<td>'.date('d M Y [H:i:s]', filemtime($file)).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.filesize($file).' bytes</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?></table>
```

- The table is better formatted with complete row and closing tags.
- `glob()` will quickly get you a list of files.
- `filesize()` will return the size of a file in bytes.
- I'm using `filemtime()` to get the last-modified time of the file.  I'm assuming this is sufficient for your needs.  If not, you'll likely need to store an actual upload time in a database for retrieval as the file system doesn't understand that concept.  I'm formatting the result with `date()`.  An example would be: `02 Jan 2018 [06:15:27]`.

I recommend using [PHP.net](http://php.net), it's a very handy resource.

Comment: whats the best to sort these files in a way that the latest to be uploaded is it at the top of the list? – Rayobeats 18 mins ago

Comment: In that case, you'll want to perform a second loop before the loop shown in my example.  Something like this: `$sort_var=array(); foreach($files as $file){$sort_var[filemtime($file).'_'.$file]=$file;} rsort($sort_var);`  Then your second foreach would loop through `$sort_var` rather than `$files`.